# Caught in redirect loop. How do I redirect user to clean URL if GET variable does not exist?

Tags: php, loops, variables, redirect

So I have a page that will display differently depending if $_GET variables are passed to the page.

My URL:

```
/page.php?one=hello&two=world
```

Here is where I check if the URL is missing any GET variables:

```
if(empty($_GET["one"]) || empty($_GET["two"])){

    //My url is missing crucial information.
    //Send user to /page.php without GET variables

}else{

    //Excellent. My GET variables exist.
    //User stays on /page.php?one=hello&two=world

}
```

But this creates and endless loop. If the user goes directly to /page.php without GET variables they are just redirected back to /page.php.

Comment: You could just use a second file for processing the get parameters. Or try it without redirect. Write the code you want to execute on empty parameters in the if-block, the code you want to execute when all is good in the else-block

Comment: The logic doesn't make sense... "If the two required values are empty (or not defined) then redirect to page.php (where they're also not defined)" - maybe just throw an error instead, or redirect to a different page?

Comment: @scrowler I want this page to have custom URLs. 

So imagine /page.php randomly generates and sentence. The user is all like "Whoa, I really like this sentence. I'm going to share this url so I can share this generated sentence with all my best buds."

But what if the user is drunk and doesn't copy the url right. Maybe they leave off one of the GET variables. If this happens, I want the user redirected back to /page.php

I hope this helps. If not I guess I have to think of a better way to explain my issue.

Comment: Why not just redirect them to a page that is not redirecting to that page! Or if the page does redirect to the page what checks for the empty variables then set a rule to alert the user or kill there session...  simple way of getting round this would be to redirect back to another page... if (empty($_GET['one']) && empty($_GET['two']))
{
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit; 
}    or even kill the redirect to prevent the page redirecting back to the checking page.. Show us your redirect script.

Comment: So maybe you want to use `if(isset($_GET['one'], $_GET['two']) && $_GET['one'] == '' && $_GET['two'] == '')) { header("Location: page.php"); } else { ... }` - that way you check if the variables are *set* but empty, where `empty($_GET['one'])` will return true if the variables aren't set at all

Comment: @scrowler almost on the same wave length there mate :) lol

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['one'])||isset($_GET['two'])){
.......//Something
}else{
.......//something
}
```

This will work!